# using (time f) always gives higher value the first time

Tags: clojure

I was trying to profile the below bock of code. r is an alias for clojure.core.reducers ns -

```
(time (->> (range 100)
       (r/map inc)
       (r/map inc)
       (r/map inc)
       (into [])))
```

The first time it runs I get a very high value (7ms), and on subsequent runs it in the range of 0.4-0.6 ms. What is the reason for the difference between the first time it is profiled and subsequent runs ?

Also why is there a small difference in time between each subsequent run ?

When I tried to profile the code below -

```
(time (->> (range 1000)
       (r/map inc)
       (r/map inc)
       (r/map inc)
       (r/fold conj)))
```

these are time times I got -

```
"Elapsed time: 2.394621 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1.085808 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.633257 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.716865 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.689908 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.691848 msecs"
```

Similar pattern - it starts with a very high value, and then eventually decreases. In this case the first 2 values were high, as opposed to just the first value being high in the first case. What is happening below the covers ?

Comment: AFAIK this is related to jvm's jit compilation strategy. Cannot find the related SO topic though.

Comment: Yup. You'll see this not for Clojure, but for pretty much *everything* that runs on the JVM (or anything else that's JITted).

Comment: ...there's a reason it's conventional to throw out the first several runs when doing microbenchmarks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the first run always much slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741921/why-is-the-first-run-always-much-slower)

Comment: ...heck, the first time through a loop is often slower even in non-JITted software (f/e, code written in C), because your caches aren't yet hot.

Comment: If you want to microbenchmark, you are better off using criterium, which takes care of heating up the jvm (and your cpu)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so the time variance is because the time that JIT takes for code compilation the first time ?

Comment: @murtaza52, ...kinda; it's already compiled to JVM bytecode, but on the first run, the machine code isn't optimized yet. The JIT compiler instruments the machine code, watches which branches are taken in practice, and then replaces it with better machine code later, after it knows which paths through the code are more common/likely. Whether an initial compilation pass happens on bytecode load or first run is an implementation detail; would need to look it up for any given JVM version, but either way, that first version of the machine code is slower than the later, refined version.

Comment: @murtaza52, ...and, as previously mentioned, whether your CPU caches are hot also matters. If you ran the same code and accessed the same data recently, it's less likely to need to be loaded from (slower) system memory. Then again, you take a ding on that every time the JIT compiler swaps out machine code with a better version, so it's not a smooth start slow -> get faster curve.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy please post it as an answer, you have answered my question.

Comment: Use the Criterium library for doing timings. It's excellent. I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, *especially* for any language with JIT compilation.

First, the JIT end:

Your JVM may or may not compile Java bytecode to machine code when that bytecode is loaded -- but either way, that initial bytecode will not yet be optimized based on actual runtime timings. After code on the JVM has been run (and to an increasing extent the more it's run), the JIT compiler is able to collect details on which codepaths are most frequently followed, and optimize to be faster in the most common cases.

Second, the factors common to all modern CPU architectures: The first time machine code is run, the code and the data it operates on get loaded from RAM (which is slow) into the CPU cache (which is fast). If it's run again on the same CPU without being evicted (by other processes or threads being scheduled in and needing the same cache space), you're going to see much better performance.

Good microbenchmarking tools already take account of these issues on your behalf. [Hugo Duncan's Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) is well-reputed, and will give you results that factor out these startup costs to the extent possible.